# source catkin_ws/src/setup.bash after each reboot?

Tags: ros, catkin, source, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with ROS-groovy.

I followed the tutorial "InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment" on how to create a catkin workspace.

When I reboot my laptop I've to

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

to find packages in catkin_ws/src with the command

```
rospack find <package_name>
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong or I'm misinformed.

I appreciate your help,
Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118901/source-catkin_ws/src/setup.bash-after-each-reboot-?/) by [Matt_Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/10931/matt_matt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matt_Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/10931/matt_matt/) on 2014-01-17**:
I tried your solution and it worked. Thank you!

**Comment by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) on 2014-01-17**:
If Kamiccolo's answer was correct could you please "accept" it?

**Comment by [Matt_Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/10931/matt_matt/) on 2014-01-18**:
Sorry, I oversaw the "mark this answer as correct button" so I just voted it up. Now i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could You be more specific on the system You're running, please?

In general case, after adding `source path_to_your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to `~/.bashrc` it should work automagically on each start-up or new terminal run. More on this topic: [step 8](http://nootrix.com/2012/05/ros-installation/)

Another solution would be adding an [`alias`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-bash-alias-examples/#more-4009) for mentioned `source` call. Something like:

```
alias robot1_ws="source path_to_your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"
alias robot2_ws="source path_to_your/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash"
alias robot3_ws="source path_to_your/catkin_ws3/devel/setup.bash"
```

in Your `~/.bash_aliases` file. To `source` one of those workspaces You'd have only to type `robot1_ws`, `robot2_ws` or `robot3_ws` in the terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) with karma: 91 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6